# How to connect WSL cardano-cli to Daedalus cardano-node on Windows?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, daedalus

I have the Daedalus wallet/node desktop app installed on Windows 10. And I also have the `cardano-cli` set up on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04.

How can I point my WSL `cardano-cli` to the `cardano-node` that's inside Daedalus?

Most instructions say to do this:

```
export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=$(ps ax | grep -v grep | grep cardano-wallet | grep mainnet | sed -r 's/(.*)node-socket //')
```

But that's in WSL and I don't think it can see Daedalus in the Windows OS.

So, how do I find the socket path of Daedalus on Windows 10? And after that can I simply assign it to `CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. WSL is a linux container on windows that expects a POSIX socket and Daedalus on windows uses named pipes. They aren't compatible. You may be able to symlink the state directory from Daedalus to WSL and stop daedalus and run a node in WSL, although I've never tested this and don't know if it would work.